# Windows believes it's in English, but it's in French, how to force it to be really in English?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, language-pack, system-administration

Initially I had a French Windows 10 *Professional* (this is a work station, so several settings are controlled by the corporate admins, but I am admin on the machine).

But I like my interfaces to be in English, as well as the English language for Windows.
However being in France, there is only french keyboards, so I need to keep the French keyboard layout. As well as date, time and numbers format.

So, I downloaded the English language pack, switched to the English as main Windows language, set a French keyboard for the English language, and removed the US keyboard.
[image]

**The problem**: *Now my Windows believes it's in English, but it's actually in French... and I don't see how to force the Windows language to be in English.*

[image]
I have this one
[image]

observe, I have only one language in the language list, but however, in the Windows Display language list, I have two, the English and the French. Also, in the right column "Do you have the questions", the suggestions are in English... so, it's like a mix between the languages but it shouldn't be something like this.

[image]

The most probably, as my OS is managed by my organisation, it was forced to be the French one, but how does Windows contradicts itself... There seem to be a bug in this Windows setting...

also, I have only one language - English, but I've changed the keyboard to be French, however, I don't understand why I have now two languages in the language switch:

[image]

I know it seems confusing, my last screenshot indicates my keyboard is French (Clavier Français) but the language is "English (US)". I replaced the initial LANG/KEYBOARD from US/US to US/FR to have only one language - English, but the keyboard (as it physically is) keep French.

However, is not clear from where the US/US keyboard reappeared in the list, as I have removed it...

Bellow is the configuration from the `ControlPanel=>Region`
[image]

Comment: Your last screenshot is indicates your keyboard layout is English.  If you create a new user what language is the interface?  Did you install English or French version of Windows 10 originally!

Comment: @Ramhound, I edited the OP to better explain the problem

Comment: @Serge The question is which Windows edition is installed. For example, if it's Windows 10 Pro, open the store and search for: Local Experience Pack and then choose the English package and install it. For example, this would be the link to the EN / US package:[Language Experience Pack US](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/english-united-states-local-experience-pack/9pdscc711rvf). If you then want to change the login screen too, you have to do the following: Press Windows and R at same time, type **control** and press enter. In the control panel change **View by** to large or small icons.

Comment: Then click on **Region** , **Administrative** and then on **Copy Settings**. Mark the check box: Welcome Screen and system account and optional "New user accounts" and click on "okay" and "Restart now".

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy I have Windows 10 Pro, for the rest please see my last picture from the edited OP, is seems it's English, but is not, because you see the interface is in French, even if it says it's English.

Comment: @Serge Has the Language Experience Package been installed or not? If not, do so. Then log out of the user account and log in. Then the Windows settings for example should be in English.

Comment: @Serge - You didn't answer my question about the new user.  "However, is not clear from where the US/US keyboard reappeared in the list, as I have removed it." - This is an easy problem to fix.  The real problem is the interface being the incorrect language.

Comment: @Tekkie_Boy, I installed it, the language pack, as I write in my OP. How otherwise could I use the English in the list of available windows languages.... Every time I restart my computer there is something that is synchronized with the company server, cause I need to authentificate myself and there is some process that is happeling... maybe it rollbacks register values to the company "standard", I have, by eg, managed corporate bookmarks in Chrome, but the windows language is not comprehensible, how does it work...

Comment: duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1617837/465922