# Windows 10 does not change the display language

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-domain

Suppose I am in France, but want my Windows on my corporate (normally, in French) computer, to be in English. I tried to change this and finally I am here:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-WinSystemLocale
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            English (United States)
    
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-WinUserLanguageList
LanguageTag     : en-US
Autonym         : English (United States)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : Anglais (États-Unis)
ScriptName      : Latin
InputMethodTips : {0409:0000040C}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
    
PS C:\windows\system32>_
```

[image]

I restarted multiple times the computer. Nothing does. It stays in French, the "English" combobox value of the "Windows Display Language" has any effect.

[image]

Also, it seems there is any way to remove the second "French" language from that box:

[image]

Windows Feedback **Bug declared [here](https://aka.ms/AAau2zj)**, please up-vote if you consider this as a bug
https://aka.ms/AAau2zj

Comment: There are multiple locale settings which can be changed, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/get-winsystemlocale?view=win10-ps does that return `fr-FR` or `en-US`? There are a bunch of other locale settings which need to be changed to `fr-FR`. There's also `get-culture`

Comment: @spikey_richie I updated the OP to reflect the powershell command result

Comment: [What locale is your user?](https://www.isunshare.com/images/article/windows-10/change-system-locale-in-windows-10/choose-change-system-locale.png).  If you don’t have Administrator access have an Administrator provide this information and [edit] your question.  The locale can also be handled with a group policy so it’s possible your system despite you trying to change it yourself will not respect your local changes.  If that’s the case your domain administrator can make the change for you

Comment: @Ramhound please see updated OP with a new picture from the "old" Control Panel

Comment: any workaround would be found here, that is clearly a Windows bug...

Comment: added a Windows Feedback problem reference to upvote ;)